# wso2 api manager 2.6.0 Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://{uri.var.hostname}:{uri.var.portnum}/oauth2/token

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am observing ocasional errors while invoking the token endpoint, I can't tell why sometimes it works fine an some others if fails.

The invocation is made using the JWT bearer grant to exchange JWT token for an access token.

The log shows:

Token endpoint suspension:

```
INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - STATUS = Executing token 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 303001, ERROR_MESSAGE = Currently , Address endpoint : [ Name : AnonymousEndpoint ] [ State : SUSPENDED ] {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
...
WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} - Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://{uri.var.hostname}:{uri.var.portnum}/oauth2/token - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Thu Feb 11 18:21:38 CET 2021 {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
```

What could be the reason why it fails? Advice to fix it?

**UPDATE**

I've located the token anonymous endpoint configuration in `repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/_TokenAPI_.xml`:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="_WSO2AMTokenAPI_" context="/token">
    <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/*" faultSequence="_token_fault_">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="uri.var.portnum" expression="get-property('keyManager.port')"/>
            <property name="uri.var.hostname" expression="get-property('keyManager.hostname')"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                     <http uri-template="https://{uri.var.hostname}:{uri.var.portnum}/oauth2/token">
                        <timeout>
                            <duration>60000</duration>
                            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                        </timeout>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
    <handlers>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerCacheExtensionHandler"/>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.common.SynapsePropertiesHandler"/>
    </handlers>
</api>
```

How can I turn it into a named endpoint and disable the suspension?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your token endpoint is created inside your Synapse configuration itself. It is configured as an [anonymous endpoint](https://medium.com/@pubududp/esb-what-does-it-mean-by-an-anonymous-endpoint-or-a-sequence-2a416830bb84).

The error code of 303001 indicates that your token Endpoint is not ready to connect. Thus the token endpoint is not active at all the time and getting inactive after some transactions.

It is not created as a separate endpoint and persisted in DB or File system. It is recommended to use a named endpoint instead of your anonymous one.

And disable the [suspension](http://%20https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Prevent+API+Suspension) of the endpoint.

```
<suspendOnFailure>
    <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
    <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
    <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
    <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
</suspendOnFailure>
```

Comment: Could you have a look at the updated question? I would appreciate some help to turn it into a named endpoint disabling the suspension